# How get socket.io Broadcast messages on client side?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying send a broadcast message from Server to clients, follow the docs avaiable at https://socket.io/docs/
And doesn't work

I tryed of two forms at server side

```
io.emit('update_status',{ device: device.id, status: 'Dead'});
```

or

```
socket.broadcast.emit({ device: device.id, status: 'Dead'});
```

At Client Side

```
socket.on('update_status',function(data) {
                console.log('update_status',data);
            });
```

or

```
socket.on('message',function(data) {
         console.log('message ',data);
});
```

Any message arrives at client side.

I need to understand what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

I found the solution with the help of @Azka. I do not know why, but using the variable socket soon after initiate the socket on the client side works, started to receiving messages.

```
var socket = io ();
socket.on ('message', function (data) {
                 console.log ('message', data);
});
```

Another thing with helps me is using debug at client side.
Paste at Browser console to read all incoming messages

localStorage.debug = 'socket.io-client:socket';

The Problem is: After the socket was added at room stopped to Receive Broadcast

Any sugestions?

Comment: How you initiate connection between client and server?

Comment: I initiate following the docs, direct messages arrive at client, but broadcast messages not arrives at client.

Comment: have u try io.emit('broadcast', { device: device.id, status: 'Dead'});